# ImportError: No module named websocket

Tags: python, macos, websocket, module, package

I tried importing websocket, but python returns
`ImportError: no module named websocket.`

I checked sys.path, and the directory that the websocket package is in, Library/Python/3.7/lib/python/site-packages, is included. I also confirmed that there's `__init__.py` in the package.

I tried importing the other modules in Library/Python/3.7/lib/python/site-packages: none of them can be imported.

Why can't I import any of the packages in that path?

Comment: Try installing it with:  `sudo pip install websocket` or `sudo apt-get install python3-websocket`

Comment: Tried. Doesn't work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may have more than one python version installed.

For example, the script you are running is defined to run with python 2.7 but your default python version is >=3 so pip will install websocket for python 3 only.

Try using
`pip2 install websocket`

Also check to see if you have `#!/usr/bin/python2.7` in your first line of the script

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes you have to restart your ide when installing some libraries. And in others you may need to reboot the whole system

Comment: What do you mean by restarting my ide?

Answer (score 0):

Whatever editor you are using to write your code. I use Visual Studio Code. On some libraries, I have to restart the editor when installing a library. I had to restart Atom just adding plugins.

Comment: I installed the libraries through terminal.

Comment: So do I. Sometimes I have to restart VSC